# Why does bash on windows say "No such file or directory"?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run my shell script with bash on Windows, but it says no such file. The file definitely exists (I checked it from the command line)

```
# Tried all of these, and they all fail
bash C:/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh
bash /c/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh
bash -c /c/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh
bash C:\Users\myuser\Testing\my_script.sh
```

I just get:

> /bin/bash: C:/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh: No such file or directory

The file *does* exist:

```
dir C:\myuser\Testing\my_script.sh
```

> Volume in drive C is Windows
>   Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX
>
> Directory of C:\myuser\Testing\my_script.sh
>
> 08/15/2019  10:42 AM             7,783 my_script.sh
>               1 File(s)          7,783 bytes
>               0 Dir(s)  370,855,380,416 bytes free

Bash version:

```
bash --version
```

> GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>   Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>
> This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

```
bash which bash
```

> /bin/bash

**Using Windows 10, running from `cmd` shell.**

Comment: Please copy/paste and entire line of your input and the output. (Set `PS1='#'` or some such if you need to anonymize.)  Also show the output of `ls -l /c/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh` and `which bash`, and maybe `bash --version`.

Comment: @PaulHodges The above lines of code *are* my entire input (e.g. `bash C:/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh`). For output it says (depending on the one used above): `/bin/bash: C:/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh: No such file or directory`

Also, I'm on windows using the `cmd` window to run this, so there is no "ls", but I can print what I get for "dir"

Comment: @PaulHodges Updated with info requested

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a hard to find/figure out answer as most examples show accessing the "C" drive as `/c/Users/myuser` but since it treats the linux subsystem as "sort of" a different OS, that drive needs to be mounted. So the correct path is: `/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh`

```
bash /mnt/c/Users/myuser/Testing/my_script.sh
```

The key is the **`/mnt`** at the beginning.

Comment: I left out the slash before mnt!  Thank you!

Comment: Wow, saved me so much time!

Comment: Is it still OK to run a shell script on disk e? I tried bash /mnt/e/location/to/shell but still report "No such file or directory"